# Hide Keyboard when tap on Ext.Form.Select

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm looking for the event that fires when you tap on a select but I can't find it.
I'm also looking for a way to hide the keyboard.

It doing this because I have a TextField and a Select in a Panel and I want to hide the keyboard if the user write something in the TextField and then uses the Select.

Could somebody help me find a solution for that problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to do what I wanted to do like so:

**Hiding the keyboard**

```
function hideKeyboard() {
     var activeElement = document.activeElement;
     activeElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly'); 
     activeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
     Ext.defer(function() {
         activeElement.blur();
         activeElement.removeAttribute('readonly');
         activeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
     }, 100);
}
```

**Detect when the picker shows (is the same as when the select field is taped)**

```
Ext.Picker.override({
    show: function() {
        if (Ext.is.Phone) { 
            hideKeyboard();
        }
        Ext.Sheet.superclass.show.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Here you go

Comment: When I do this, the keyboard never comes back when I return the form.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by customising the Select field.  See [How to create a select field in Sencha Touch like the iPhone ringtone screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720193/how-to-create-a-select-field-in-sencha-touch-like-the-iphone-ringtone-screen).

This field allows you to code for the `maskTap` event and the onscreen keyboard is not displayed.  Note that the item cannot get focus either.